# android speech RecognitionListener not working in loop

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have created a RecognitionListener for my speech recognition. Problem is when I run the application `public void onError(int errorCode)`is not getting called in loop when ever there is some error like "SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT".

But when i run the same application in debug mode and put a debug pointer in `public void onError(int errorCode)` it runs perfectly and control comes all the time when ever there is error. speech listener is not getting initialized and started and onready method is called but stops listening dont know why.

Please let me know if you have any idea why is control not coming when not running in debug mode.

```
    package com.voice.java.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.voice.jarvis.CommandProcessorImpl;
import com.voice.jarvis.JARVISActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CommandVoiceListner implements RecognitionListener{
    private static Context ctx;
    public CommandVoiceListner(){   }

    public CommandVoiceListner(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    private static SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
    private static Intent recognizerIntent;
    private String LOG_TAG = "CommandVoiceListner";
    private List<String> mResults;
    private CommandProcessorImpl commandProcessorImpl;
    private boolean isRecognitionServiceAvailable = false;

    public void startListening(){
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "context in listner : " + ctx);
        if (SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(ctx)) {
            if (isRecognitionServiceAvailable){//(speech!=null){
                speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
                mResults = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            else
                startSR();
        }
    }

    public void startSR(){
            isRecognitionServiceAvailable = true;
            speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(ctx);
            speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
            recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
                    "en");
            recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                    ctx.getPackageName());
            recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
            recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
            speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int errorCode) {
        String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEvent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResults " + results);
        isRecognitionServiceAvailable = false;
        mResults = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "starting activity from listner");
        commandProcessorImpl = new CommandProcessorImpl(ctx);
        try {
            //commandProcessorImpl.setmResults(mResults);
            commandProcessorImpl.filterUserInputText(mResults);
            //new Thread(commandProcessorImpl).start();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error occured onResult : " + e);
        }
        startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
    }

    public String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
        String message;
        switch (errorCode) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            message = "Audio recording error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            message = "Client side error";
            startListening();
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            message = "Insufficient permissions";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            message = "Network error";
            startListening();
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            message = "Network timeout";
            startListening();
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            message = "No match";
            speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            message = "RecognitionService busy";
            //startListening();
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            message = "error from server";
            startListening();
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            message = "No speech input";
            startListening();
            break;
        default:
            message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
            startListening();
            break;
        }
        return message;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet tried what you have did but I had a problem working on a recording app similar to yours (i.e when I use to debug the app it would work and in normally it would raise a exception) the problem was device dependent the recording would start before the the media recorder would be prepared but when the debug point would be applied it would get time to prepare the media recorder thus i just started the recording after a delay of 100 milliseconds and it worked
I hope this helps you some how.